# android Spinner set Text give error in setText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I am working on `EditText` and `Spinner` . When I set text for `EditText` it were fine but when I try to set text for `Spinner` it give error.

this is code for set text `EditText`

```
New_Name.setText(NewName);
```

here New_Name is `EditText`

this is code for set text `Spinner`

```
New_Quantity.setText(NewQuantity);
```

here New_Quantity is `Spinner`

this is the full code.

```
    public class UpdateFoodActivity extends Activity {
    EditText Name_Search,New_Name,New_Calorie,New_Fat,New_Protein,New_Sugar,New_carbohydrates;
    Spinner New_Quantity;
    TextView title_text;
    String SearchName,NewName,NewQuantity,NewCalorie,NewFat,NewProtein,NewSugar,Newcarbohydrates;
    FoodDbHelper foodDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Button UpdateButton;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    private Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.update_food_activity);

        Name_Search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_search);
        New_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_name);
        New_Quantity = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.new_quantity);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.quant, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        New_Quantity.setAdapter(adapter);
        New_Quantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        New_Calorie = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_calorie);
        New_Fat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_fat);
        New_Protein = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_protein);
        New_Sugar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_sugar);
        New_carbohydrates = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_vitamins);
        UpdateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        title_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        New_Name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Quantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Calorie.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Fat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Protein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Sugar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_carbohydrates.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        UpdateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        title_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


    public void searchFood(View view){
        SearchName = Name_Search.getText().toString();
        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = foodDbHelper.getFood(SearchName,sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


            NewQuantity = cursor.getString(0);
            NewCalorie = cursor.getString(1);
            NewFat = cursor.getString(2);
            NewProtein = cursor.getString(3);
            NewSugar = cursor.getString(4);
            Newcarbohydrates = cursor.getString(5);

            NewName = SearchName;
            New_Name.setText(NewName);
            New_Quantity.setText(NewQuantity);
            New_Calorie.setText(NewCalorie);
            New_Fat.setText(NewFat);
            New_Protein.setText(NewProtein);
            New_Sugar.setText(NewSugar);
            New_carbohydrates.setText(Newcarbohydrates);
            New_Name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Calorie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Fat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Protein.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Sugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_carbohydrates.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UpdateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            title_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No Dish Found " ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    }

    public void updatebutton(View view)
    {
        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String name,quantity,calorie,fat,protein,sugar,carbohydrates;
        name = New_Name.getText().toString();
        quantity = New_Quantity.getSelectedItem().toString();
        calorie = New_Calorie.getText().toString();
        fat = New_Fat.getText().toString();
        protein = New_Protein.getText().toString();
        sugar = New_Sugar.getText().toString();
        carbohydrates = New_carbohydrates.getText().toString();
        int count = foodDbHelper.updateInformation(SearchName,name,quantity,calorie,fat,protein,sugar,carbohydrates,sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),count+" dish updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,UpdateFoodActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? can you post the stacktrace

Comment: `Spinner` element hasn't got `setText()` method. You should use an `ArrayAdapter` (*for example*).

Comment: Spinner don't have setText() method. maybe you will put the whole code?

Comment: setText could not resolve here in spinner

Comment: i have update question please check it @tomloprod

Comment: in your new code, I don't see line you set text for spinner

Comment: @EmanCh The `Spinner` element **hasn't** got `setText()` method: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: @tomloprod how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

In order to add entries to the spinner you need to define an Adapter i give you an example:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("list 1");
list.add("list 2");
list.add("list 3");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.spinner_item, list);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: seems to be fine!? Mark as resolved if your question got answered

Comment: no not solve my issue i already use arrayadapter but i have problem in set text for spinner

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` likes `ListView`, need an adapter for rendering data. Adapter, in simple term, is a collection of items. (As you see `ListView` always contains list of item and also Spinner). Nevertheless, Adapter of `spinner` often a list of string. (because `spinner` just represents user choice)

In your example, You can simply create `ArrayAdapter` and assign again to `Spinner`.

```
private void setTextForSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
   String[] items = {"Stack", "Over", "Flow"};
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items); 
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

If apply above code to your example, you can change again to:

```
private void setTextForSpinner(Spinner spinner, String NewName) {
       String[] items = {NewName};
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items); 
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Hope this help :)